# Batch class is failing - giving timed out error

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, community, schedulebatch

Batch class is failing. Giving timed out error. Can anybody suggest anything?
My query is,
SELECT Id, Name FROM TestObject__c WHERE Test_Date__c < TODAY and Test_Date__c != null and isDeleted = false.

There are around 24 lac records to delete every week.

Comment: Where is the query? In the start method?

Comment: Please post the batch class code.  It's very difficult to diagnose the problem without the code.

Answer (score 1):

This query isn't well optimized, so perhaps you could optimize it as the following:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM TestObject__c WHERE Test_Date__c < TODAY ORDER BY Test_Date__c DESC
```

First, without using `ALL ROWS`, the query won't return deleted records (i.e. IsDeleted = FALSE is redundant). Secondly, using `Test_Date__c < TODAY` automatically includes the condition Test_Date__c != NULL. Thirdly, adding an `ORDER BY` clause hints at an index salesforce.com can use.

The second point, not using `Test_Date__c != NULL`, is important because checking for null or not-null can result in a full table scan, because null values aren't explicitly indexed. Doubly so, since the query can't return `Test_Date__c = NULL` records because the date operators automatically filter out NULL values.

The third point simply helps salesforce.com optimize the query by leveraging an index. All date and numeric fields are automatically indexed, so ordering a query by such a field will optimize the query.

Comment: For this query also batch is failling,
SELECT Id, Name FROM TestObject__c WHERE Test_Date__c < TODAY ORDER BY Test_Date__c DESC

Comment: Is the user running the batch a system administrator? Can you run the query with the Data Loader successfully? This batch should work just fine for administrators up to 50,000,000 rows, although I suppose non-administrators might not be able to run the query depending on the sharing model and number of records.

Comment: Yes the user is System Administrator and query is not running successfully with Data Loader also.

Comment: You may want to log a case with support, in that case. I can't see why this query would fail.

Comment: We have logged a case with salesforce. And thanks for your help @sfdcfox.